# GCM - MISMATCH SENDER ID with ionic, parse and phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

I have registered my android device with parse, but when I try to send a notification to it I get a GCM - MISMATCH SENDER ID. Parse does get the registered device and the ids look normal (I had a buddy with a native android app to look at his ids, and they look the same)

I am using the same basic functionality for ios and it works.

For ionic I had to use phonegap-plugin-push so I could get it working for both android and ios, but still no luck with android.

in package.json

```
{
  "variables": {
    "SENDER_ID": "960006459909"
  },
  "locator": "phonegap-plugin-push"
}
```

in config.xml

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.6.2">
   <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="960006459909"/>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting my deviceToken to registrationId, I parsed out the first part of the id b/c my buddy said his ID didn't have it. Turns out that was needed.

I also set up a browser api key with google developer console.

So I now receive the push notifications from android.